# iOS foreground observer is not invoked

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a observer for both background and foreground activity.

When double click on home button, background observer getting invoked. But when I choose my app immediately, **my foreground observer is not getting invoked**.
Please check this gif for demo https://raw.githubusercontent.com/billionlaughs/Demo/master/resources/foreground_issue.gif .

Tested iOS version: 13.1.2.
Code snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var uiLabelToShow: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Will be invoked when app goes to background
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myBGObserver), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
        //Will be invoked when app goes to foreground
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFGObserver), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func myBGObserver(){
        uiLabelToShow.text = "Background";
    }
    @objc func myFGObserver(){
        uiLabelToShow.text = "Foreground";
    }
}
```

Github link for my demo project : https://github.com/billionlaughs/Demo

I couldn't find any fix/reason for this issue. Please guide me to the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` is called when your app hides some how after you click the home button twice ( not stay shown scalled as your gif ) , for what you need use`UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` instead of `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`

> drawBack : initially text will contain Foreground

to solve do

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var uiLabelToShow: UILabel!
    var once = true 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Will be invoked when app goes to background
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myBGObserver), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
        //Will be invoked when app goes to foreground
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFGObserver), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func myBGObserver(){
        uiLabelToShow.text = "Background";
    }
    @objc func myFGObserver(){
        uiLabelToShow.text = once ? "Normal" : "Foreground";
        once = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just replace your second observer code with code mention below:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myFGObserver), name: .UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

because `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` is called when home button is pressed.